# How to solve the JSON Formate issue in php array Insert into database

Tags: php, arrays, json

i need to insert the JSON data into the Database,
But i have array of values like
1 customer can have multiple flower details which user can enter quantity
so N number of customers can have N Number of flower details in array as shown in the picture

[image: it has customer_id[] is in hidden text]

here is the https://jsfiddle.net/r6dtk30j/2/ for the above image

my php code is

```
public function ajax_addOrderToGroup() {

    $flower_id = $this->input->post('flower_id');
    $flower_price = $this->input->post('flower_price');
    $customer_id = $this->input->post('customer_id');
    $quantity = $this->input->post('quantity');

    $locationData = array();
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($customer_id as $key2 => $fname2) {
        $locationData['orders'][$i]['customer_id'] = $_POST['customer_id'][$key2];


        $j = 0;
        foreach ($flower_id as $key => $fname) {
            $locationData['orders'][$i]['flower_id'][$j] = $_POST['flower_id'][$key];
            $j++;
        }
        $k = 0;
        foreach ($flower_price as $key1 => $fname1) {
            $locationData['orders'][$i]['flower_price'][$k] = $_POST['flower_price'][$key1];
            $k++;
        }
        $l = 0;
        foreach ($quantity as $key1 => $fname1) {
            $locationData['orders'][$i]['quantity'][$l] = $_POST['quantity'][$key1];
            $l++;
        }
        $i++;
    }

    echo json_encode($locationData);
}
```

and the JSON result is

```
{
"orders": [
    {
        "customer_id": "21",
        "flower_id": [
            "1",
            "2"
        ],
        "flower_price": [
            "56",
            "7"
        ],
        "quantity": [
            "13",
            "2",
            "12",
            "3"
        ]
    },
    {
        "customer_id": "20",
        "flower_id": [
            "1",
            "2"
        ],
        "flower_price": [
            "56",
            "7"
        ],
        "quantity": [
            "13",
            "2",
            "12",
            "3"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Javascript:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

                                    $('#datatables').DataTable({
                                        "pagingType": "full_numbers",
                                        lengthMenu: [[2, 4, 8, -1], [2, 4, 8, "All"]],
                                        pageLength: 5,
                                        responsive: true,
                                        language: {
                                            search: "_INPUT_",
                                            searchPlaceholder: "Search records",
                                        }

                                    });

                                    $(".submit-btn").hide();
                                    var table = $('#datatables').DataTable();
                                    table.on('click', '.edit', function (e) {
                                        var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                                        var group_id = document.getElementById('group_id').value;
                                        if (group_id == 0) {
                                            notifications('Choose Group Name', 'Please Choose Group', 'danger');
                                        } else {
                                            var data = table.row($tr).data();
                                            var flower_id = data[0];
                                            var flower_name = data[1];
                                            var flower_price = $('#flower_price_' + flower_id).val();
                                            if (flower_price.length == 0) {
                                                notifications('OOPS..!', 'Required Flower Price', 'danger');
                                            } else {
                                                $(".hidden_values").append('<input type ="hidden" name="flower_id[]" value=' + flower_id + '><input type ="hidden" name="flower_price[]" value=' + flower_price + '>'); //add input box
                                                $(".flower_details").append('<tr><td>' + flower_name + '</td> <td>' + flower_price + '</td><td class="text-left"><input type="number" class="form-control" id="quantity" name="quantity[]"></td></tr>'); 
                                                $('#flower_id_' + flower_id).prop('disabled', true);

                                                e.preventDefault();
                                            }
                                        }

                                    });
                                    $('.card .material-datatables label').addClass('form-group');
                                });

                                function getCustomers() {
                                    var group_id = document.getElementById("group_id").value;
                                    $.ajax({
                                        url: baseurl + "customer/ajax_getGroupCustomerById",
                                        method: "post",
                                        data: {group_id: group_id},
                                        success: function (data) {
                                            var jsonobj = JSON.parse(data);
                                            var index = 1;
                                            var htmlText = '';
                                            for (var key in jsonobj) {
                                                htmlText += '<input type ="hidden" name="customer_id[]" class="customer_id" value=' + jsonobj[key]['customer_id'] + '>';
                                                htmlText += '<br/><h4><b>' + index++ + '.</b> Customer: <b class="text-primary">' + jsonobj[key]['first_name'] + ' ' + jsonobj[key]['last_name'] + '</b><h4>';
                                                htmlText += '<table class="table table-striped table-no-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="width:100%">' +
                                                        '<thead><tr><th>Flower Name</th><th>Flower Price</th><th>Quantity</th></tr></thead><tbody class="flower_details">' +
                                                        '</tbody></table>';

                                            }

                                            $('.customerDetails').append(htmlText);
                                        }
                                    });

                                }




                                function addGroupOrderForm() {
    var data = $("#grouporder-form").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: baseurl + "product/ajax_addOrderToGroup",
        data: data,
        beforeSend: function () {
            $("#error").fadeOut();
            $("#grouporder-submit").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-transfer"></span> &nbsp; Creating ...');
        },
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            return false;
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

HTML

```
  <div class="content">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="sticky_1">
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-offset-2 col-sm-12">
                            <select class="selectpicker" name="group_id" onchange="getCustomers()" id="group_id" data-style="btn btn-success btn-round" title="Single Select" data-size="7">
                                <option disabled selected value="0">Choose Group</option>
                                <?php
                                foreach ($group as $value) {
                                    ?>
                                    <option value="<?= $value->id ?>"><?= $value->group_name ?></option>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-header card-header-icon" data-background-color="green">
                                <i class="material-icons">assignment</i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-content">
                                <h4 class="card-title">Flowers</h4>
                                <div class="toolbar">
                                    <!--        Here you can write extra buttons/actions for the toolbar              -->
                                </div>
                                <div class="material-datatables">
                                    <table id="datatables" class="table table-striped table-no-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="width:100%">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Sno.</th>
                                                <th>Flower Name</th>
                                                <th>Price</th>
                                                <th>#</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>

                                            <?php
                                            foreach ($flowers as $value) {
                                                ?>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td><?= $value->id ?></td>
                                                    <td><?= $value->flower_name ?></td>
                                                    <td class="text-left">
                                                        <input type="number" placeholder="Flower Price" class="form-control flower_price" name="flower_price" id="flower_price_<?= $value->id ?>">
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <input type="button" class="hidden-xs btn btn-warning btn-raised btn-sm edit" name="flower_id" value="Add" id="flower_id_<?= $value->id ?>">
                                                        <input type="button" class="visible-xs btn btn-warning btn-sm edit" name="flower_id" value="+" id="flower_id_<?= $value->id ?>">
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            <?php } ?>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- end content-->
                        </div>
                        <!--  end card  -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-12 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12">
                            <form id="grouporder-form" name="grouporder_form" role="form" style="display: block;" method="post">
                                <div class="customerDetails">
                                    <div class="hidden_values"></div>
                                </div>

                                <center>
                                    <button type="submit" name="finish" id="grouporder-submit" class="btn btn-finish btn-fill btn-success btn-wd submit-btn">
                                        <span class="spinner"><i class="icon-spin icon-refresh" id="spinner"></i></span> Submit
                                    </button>
                                </center>
                            </form>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

but this is wrong one its not in dependency formate for quantity is getting for both customers

How to resolve this issue 
Please help me regarding this issue

Comment: that's a strange structure. Better (and more normal) would be simply a list of flower objects for each customer e.g. `"orders": [
    {
        "customer_id": "21",
        "flowers": [
            { "id" : 1, "price": 56, "quantity": 13}, {"id"; 2, "price": 7, "quantity": 2 }
        ],` etc

Comment: But as to why it's getting the output confused, we'd need to see the input data to be certain.

Comment: There seems to be a logical mistake in your request / way to post your data to page: it seems that you secondary arrays `'flower_id`, `'flower_price'`, `'quantity'` are not dependant to any customer or order id. So at the the end you'll get same results for all your orders with these loops. If this info is in the array keys for example, the way to create your arrays content should depend on this.

Comment: Even can try that @ADyson i can do that but how quantity can be associate with that customer array

Comment: Yeah..! what is the best method to resolve this
 main issue is dependency @Kaddath

Comment: @GssVenkatesh that depends on how you're creating the input data. But you didn't show us the HTML or any JavaScript (if you are using JavaScript to submit).

Comment: @ADyson i posted the  https://jsfiddle.net/r6dtk30j/2/  in question
you can check here

Comment: @GssVenkatesh Ok I can look, but as per https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic all relevant code must be shown **within the question** (not in external websites), otherwise your question can be closed down as not containing enough relevant information. The idea is not to rely on 3rd party links which can change or die in the future (making the question useless to future readers)

Comment: @ADyson

I Modified the Question as per the stackoverflow rules